# Is it possible to get metrics of SQS or SNS message attributes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have an SQS queue that receives filtered messages of an SNS and need to gather statistics about messages based on message attributes.

**Example:** suppose queue Q listening events on S, S sends messages with some message attribute `attribute that belongs {A, B, C}`. Q only filters only messages with attribute equals to A or B. That works like a charm, but now we want to know how many messages with attribute equals A, and how many with attribute equal B are incoming.

Is there a simple way to do it? Changing the architecture is not desired.

Thanks in advance

Comment: idk anywhere message attributes would be logged.  You might have to generate those metrics yourself.  hopefully somebody else has a better idea.  Good luck!

Comment: You can actually do that if you have separate topics with filtering policy dedicated for simple attribute for example dedicated for attribute A , attribute B  instead of single sns topic, there are metrics like `NumberOfNotificationsDelivered`, `NumberOfNotificationsFilteredOut`, why topics should be different because there is a dimension `TopicName` which will allow to monitor based on different topics which is not possible if you use a single topic for filtering all attributes.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-monitoring-using-cloudwatch.html

Comment: I'm going to say the most obvious thing but can you not keep a count record when you process the messages from queue ?

Comment: Both changing architecture to have multiple queues or record a counter works. Was just wondering if there are native/simpler ways to do it.